Get inner text of multiple <p> with its corresponding <h2>?
I have some VBA coding experience, but I am still an newbie in Web Scraping.
I face the following problem:
I am trying to scrape  the article text by getting all the <p> tags that come after <h2> tags.
The example HTML code is:
<div class="text-article_inside"> 
   <p>Paragraph0</p>

   <h2>Heading Text1</h2>

   <p>Paragraph1</p>
   <p>Paragraph2</p>

   <h2>Heading Text2</h2>

   <p>Paragraph3</p>
   <p>Paragraph4</p>
   <p>Paragraph5</p>

I know how to do this in case I have only <p> tags followed by only <h2> tags, I can then use getElementsbyTagName to first loop through all <p> tags and then loop through all <h2> tags. The problem that I face is that these 2 tags are constantly interchanging in the article, so the method I tried above will not work, as it break the order of the text.
I've found a lot of similar questions in Python and in Java, but none of them use VBA.
Does anyone know of a way to scrape the needed data in VBA?
My attempt:
Set HTMLCs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each HTMLC In HTMLCs

        If HTMLC.getAttribute("className") Like "text-article__inside" Then
        
            Set pTags = HTMLC.getElementsByTagName("p")
            
            N = pTags.Length + HTMLC.getElementsByTagName("h2").Length
            
            ReDim NewsContent(N)

            For Each pTag In pTags

                NewsContent(i) = pTag.innerText
                i = i + 1

            Next pTag

        End If
    
Next HTMLC

How should I handle the <h2> tag?

Use getElementsbyTagName to get the h2 elements, and then while you iterate over those, make use of the nextSibling property, to advance to the next node one by one? And keep doing that, as long as the nodeName of the current node is p?

Did you check my answer below?

Using your sample HTML, something like this may help you as suggested by @C3roe ;
Sub Test()
    Dim strHTML As String, objHTML As Object, divArticlesInside As Object
    Dim i As Integer, h2Tags As Object, j As Integer, Node As Object
    
    strHTML = "    <div class=""text-article_inside"">              " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph0</p>                           " & _
              "         <h2>Heading Text1</h2>                      " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph1</p>                           " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph2</p>                           " & _
              "         <h2>Heading Text2</h2>                      " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph3</p>                           " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph4</p>                           " & _
              "         <p>Paragraph5</p>                           "
              
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
    
    objHTML.body.innerHTML = strHTML
    
    Set divArticlesInside = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    
    For i = 0 To divArticlesInside.Length - 1
        If divArticlesInside(i).ClassName = "text-article_inside" Then
            Set h2Tags = divArticlesInside(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")
            
            For j = 0 To h2Tags.Length - 1
                If h2Tags(i).NextSibling.TagName = "P" Then
                    Set Node = h2Tags(j).NextSibling
                    Do
                        MsgBox Node.innerText
                        Set Node = Node.NextSibling
                        If Node Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    Loop While Node.TagName = "P"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    Set objHTML = Nothing
End Sub


Sub Test()
Dim strHTML As String, objHTML As Object, divArticlesInside As Object
Dim i As Integer, h2Tags As Object, j As Integer, Node As Object
strHTML = "    <div class=""text-article_inside"">              " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph0</p>                           " & _
          "         <h2>Heading Text1</h2>                      " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph1</p>                           " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph2</p>                           " & _
          "         <h2>Heading Text2</h2>                      " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph3</p>                           " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph4</p>                           " & _
          "         <p>Paragraph5</p>                           "
          
Set objHTML = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")

objHTML.body.innerHTML = strHTML

Set divArticlesInside = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")

For i = 0 To divArticlesInside.Length - 1
    If divArticlesInside(i).ClassName = "text-article_inside" Then
        Set h2Tags = divArticlesInside(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")
        
        For j = 0 To h2Tags.Length - 1
            If h2Tags(i).NextSibling.TagName = "P" Then
                Set Node = h2Tags(j).NextSibling
                Do
                    MsgBox Node.innerText
                    Set Node = Node.NextSibling
                    If Node Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While Node.TagName = "P"
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

Set objHTML = Nothing

End Sub

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's not different then my answer.
